# Переход к конкретным активити

Tags: java, android, activity, recyclerview, adapter

Есть адаптер, который использую для нескольких `recyclerView` в разных  фрагментах.

В каждом из списков я произвожу нажатие по элементам, по нажатию на которое, меня переносит в активити.

```
final Context context = ((View)personViewHolder.personPhoto.getParent()).getContext();
    ((View)personViewHolder.personPhoto.getParent()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Всё бы хорошо, но т.к. я использую данный адаптер для нескольких фрагментов, то мне не очень подходит такой вариант, так всегда по нажатию на 1-ый элемент в списке меня переносит в `MainActivity` для всех фрагментов.

Еще раз, ***проблема***:
Не могу для каждого списка в разных фрагментах реализовать переход к конкретным активностям/фрагментам.

Дополнительно нашёл [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894060/6387618), но не знаю как его запилить и вообще что он подходит, может кого то натолкнёт на мысль, так как с адаптерами я пока еще на "Вы".

Полный код адаптера:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
    }
}

List<Person> persons;

public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int position) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(position).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(position).description);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(position).photoId);

    final Context context = ((View)personViewHolder.personPhoto.getParent()).getContext();
    ((View)personViewHolder.personPhoto.getParent()).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
                    break;
            }
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}
```

Код одного из моих фрагментов(они лишь отличаются методом `initializeAdapter`)

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

List<Person> persons;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public SecondFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
}

private void initializeData() {
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "test", R.drawable.profile));
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать разными способами.

- Можно поведение при нажатии изменять в зависимости от какого-либо значения. Это значение можно установить сразу в конструкторе адаптера.

  ```
  public static class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
  ...
      final int someFlag;
  ....

      public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons, int someFlag){
          this.persons = persons;
          this.someFlag = someFlag;
      }
  }
  ```

  И в методе **onClick** учитывать это значение.

  Просто установите это значение при создании адаптера

  ```
  adapter = new RVAdapter(persons, flag);
  ```
- Еще можно в каждом отдельном фрагменте определять действия при нажатии на элементы списка. Для этого можно использовать интерфейсы.

  ```
  public interface OnRVItemClickListener{
      void onRVItemClick(int position);
  }
  ```

  Адаптер тогда должен выглядеть следующим образом:

  ```
  public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
  ...
      final OnRVItemClickListener listener;
  ...

      public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons, OnRVItemClickListener listener){
          this.persons = persons;
          this.listener = listener;
      }
  }
  ...
  ```

  В методе onClick мы вызываем метод **onRVItemClick(int position)** инстанса этого интерфеса:

  ```
  @Override
  onClick(View v){
      listener.onRVItemClick(position);
  }
  ```

  И при создании адаптера в каждом фрагменте вы явно указываете что делать при нажатии:

  ```
  private void initializeAdapter() {
      RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons, new RVItemClickListener(){
          @Override
          onRVItemClick(int position){
              Intent intent;
              switch(position){
                  case 0:
                      intent = ....
                  break;
                  case 1:
                      intent = ....
                  break;
                  .....
              }
              getActivity().startActivity(intent);
          }
      });
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  ```

Можно еще как нибудь сделать. Это первое что пришло в голову. И думаю самое простое. Но не самое элегантное решение наверное (особенно первый способ).

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию, но можно чуть побольше конкретики, т.к. не получается перенести Вашу задумку к себе в приложение.
Интерфейс OnRVItemClickListener мы объявляем во фрагменте?
Да и с полным кода адаптера очень много конфликтов возникает.

Comment: @Vadim Morozov, Исправил код. Это все невнимательность.

Comment: при попытке добавления intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); во фрагмент, в методе initializeAdapter выделяет красным context. Не подскажете как правильно откорректировать?

Comment: Вам нужен контекст той активити в которой находится фрагмент. Его можно получить: context = getActivity();

Comment: Я объявляю его прямо в этом методе, после чего он предлагает декларировать его final и сразу ломается весь метод

Comment: Покажи как ты этот метод реализовал. Передай вместо context      getActivity()

Comment: Спасибо, была неточность с конструктором в адаптере.

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` подразумевает не только инициализацию адаптера, но и классов `ViewHolder`, Вы можете воспользоваться ими и отпределять, какая активити должна открываться в зависимости от класса, представляющего визуалку, например такая реализация:

```
    /**
     * Выбирает нужный тип визуалки
     *
     * @param position - позиция элемента
     * @return int - тип визуалки
     */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //в данном случае элементы списка отличаются классом, можно определять и по другим параметрам объекта, как вам удобнее
        Object item = mItems.get(position);
        if (item instanceof Message) {
            return 0;
        } else if (item instanceof TalkItems.TalkDate) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Выбирает нужную визуалку по её типу
     *
     * @param parent   - родительская визуалка
     * @param viewType - тип визуалки
     * @return ViewHolder|null визуалка
     */
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(TalkActivity.this);
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                return new MessageView(
                        inflater.inflate(R.layout.talk_message_my, parent, false)
                );
            case 1:
                return new DateView(
                        inflater.inflate(R.layout.talk_date, parent, false)
                );
            default:
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    throw new AssertionError("Неизвестный тип визуалки");
                }
                return null;
        }
    }

    private class MessageView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        MessageView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            final Context context = getApplicationContext();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class DateView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        DateView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            final Context context = getApplicationContext();
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Если ваши элементы списка имеют одинаковую визуалку, но разный "контент", то можно воспользоваться следующим методом:

```
/**
     * В данном примере используем один класс MessageView, новый класс ниже
     * Заполнение визуальной составляющей элемента
     *
     * @param holder   - пустая визуалка
     * @param position - позиция элемента
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder == null) {
            return;
        }
        Object item = mItems.get(position);
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        MessageView mesHolder = (MessageView) holder;
        if (item instanceof Message) {
            mesHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                }
            });
        } else if (item instanceof DateItem) {
            mesHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ThirdActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class MessageView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;

        MessageView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, только не очень понимаю как правильно использовать DateView  и MessageView, в роли чего они выступают? Моих списков во фрагментах?

Comment: @VadimMorozov нет, это "холдеры" для элементов списка, таким образом вы можете для каждого из типов элементов прописать нужное Вам поведение при нажатии на элемент. Впрочем, если у Вас визуалка для них одинаковая, то можно обойтись и без разных "холдеров", а логику вынести в метод `onBindViewHolder` (обновлю в ответе)

Comment: да, одинаковая. Спасибо жду.

Comment: @VadimMorozov вот, обновил. В данном случае различие в поведении идёт от типа объекта, если объекты у Вас одного класса, можете определять поведение по наличию/отсутствию каких-либо параметров объекта или ещё как.

Answer (score 0):

1) Реализуйте в каждом списке хранение списка ссылок. Например `public ArrayList<Intent> listMenu;`, например, вот в таком адаптере (я сделал просто как BaseAdapter, чтобы быстрее)

```
//это пример реализации
public class TestAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public ArrayList<Intent> listMenu;

    public Intent getMenuItem(int position, Context context) {
        if (position > (listMenu.size() - 1)) return new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        else return listMenu.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) При создании адаптера списка - записывайте сразу ссылки для этого списка.

3) Реализуйте метод получения элемента Intent

```
//это пример реализации
    public Intent getMenuItem(int position, Context context) {
            if (position > (listMenu.size() - 1)) return new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            else return listMenu.get(position);
        }
```

4) При работе с recyclerView, получайте нужный вам объект списка.

```
//это пример реализации
public void onClick(View view) {
    int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
    Intent intent = mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getMenuItem(context, itemPosition);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: Если правильно Вас понял, вы предлагаете создавать список ссылок для каждого адаптера, но моя идея заключается в том, чтобы использовать один адаптер для нескольких списков.